# why does programmers use public always in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning CodeIgniter (CI). I have seen CI supports OOP concepts but I am wondering in every example all over the web and forums, method declared in Controllers use public keyword. I think this is not a dumb question. Even in CI userguide I have seen they always use public keyword. Then what happens to encapsulation?

can you help me to clear this.

Comment: I am talk about not using private methode not using public keyword.

Comment: What has encapsulation do with the public keyword?

Comment: your comment makes no sense to be honest.

Comment: then in model we can declare methodes as private. since we dont directly access model methodes via url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we all know CI is [MVC frame work](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html)

[image]

As the figure show the the view can call the controller and the model.
controller can call  the model and view and the model can call a view .
in this cases most of  the methods in controllers are called by the view and this function have the logic to process that request from the View.We can write private methods in controllers and model, this can only called form the same Class(As you says, Most of the examples try to illustrate a features on CI , there is no need of writing private methods ie, you didn't familiar  in private methods-this will only used in more structured applications ).There is no matter about the encapsulation and all.``

Answer (score 2):

Methods in controller are actually called by CI itself. If its not public CI can not call and your controller will not work. Thats why all the action methods need to be `public`. You can make other method `private` or `protected`.

Comment: Sure but it will default to public method anyway. Code works fine without it. I would say this is just good practice to declare it public.

Comment: In PHP 5 code works fine because of PHP 4 compatibility.

Comment: Cool. But what developers programming now need to take PHP4 in mind? CI from v2 doesn't even support PHP4 anymore.

Comment: Sorry, CI actully hasn't dropped support for PHP4, but still the same consideration... (Why is the 'Delete comment' button not accessible in iOS?)

Answer (score 1):

I would say if you want to follow good programming practice and write easy-to-follow code, add `public` to your methods. Otherwise don't. ( I know I will get some of you orthodox programmers after me now!)

PHP5 methods defaults to `public` where not stated.

> Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php